# Does the Google OR-Tools CP-SAT support relaxation method to sovle MIQP?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I applied the CP-SAT sovler to sovle a MIQP problem, and it found a optimat result successfully. Do I need to further consider the relaxation method for the problem? Does the CP-SAT sovler support relaxation?

Comment: That's a very good question, keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the second part of the [CPAIOR 2020 master class on Constraint Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmy1ddn4cyw).

Yes, the solver uses a lot of MIP techniques (presolve, relaxation, cuts) including quadratic cuts.
These are all linears, so nothing using cones.